# Installation’s version (3.3.1) is not consistent with the reported version (3.3.3)

Tags: upgrade, ee3

A couple of weeks ago I updated ExpressionEngine from 3.3.1 to 3.3.3. I followed the update guide https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/update.html exactly when doing this.

The upgrade went fine and in the footer of the Admin panel it is showing the version as 3.3.3.

Today I logged in and at the top of the Admin panel it has a warning message which says:
"Your ExpressionEngine installation’s version (3.3.1) is not consistent with the reported version (3.3.3). Please update your installation of ExpressionEngine again."

The footer is still showing that version 3.3.3 is installed.

Does anyone know why this would suddenly start appearing and what to check to see the actual version installed? As far as we're aware no rollbacks or files in system/* have been modified other than template files and some CSS used by the frontend of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out myself and was my own error but thought I'd post this in case it happens to anyone else.

I needed to review some settings in `system/user/config/config.php`. This contains the following

`$config['app_version'] = '3.3.3';`

Unfortuantely I was using NetBeans and it hadn't re-synchronised the files from the server to my local copy after the upgrade. So the value of this variable was 3.3.1 as opposed to 3.3.3. When the file was re-uploaded it obviously used the local copy. After changing the value back to 3.3.3 the error disappeared.

Interestingly there are other places that the "app version" appears in the code, such as `/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Core.php`